# Static const in javascript (typescript) class

Tags: javascript, typescript, constants

I like a single default export and to access constant values through the class definition like this:

```
MyClassDefinition.MyConstant
```

I find myself using this approach:

```
export default class MyClassDefinition {
    static get MyConstant(): number { return 1234 };
}
```

I there a less verbose way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of getter you could use a `readonly` static property. The type can be omitted as well, because TypeScript will infer it from the value.

```js
export default class MyClassDefinition {
    static readonly MyConstant = 1234;
}
```

I would also argue that the class should be `abstract` since it shouldn't be instantiated but of course that will make it a bit more verbose again.

If you only refer to the class by importing it from other files, you can even get rid of it's name entirely:

```js
export default class {
    static readonly MyConstant = 1234;
}
```

An even less verbose approach would be to export an object like this:

```js
export default {
    MyConstant: 1234
};
```

Note that with this last approach TypeScript will not prevent you from re-assigning `MyClassDefinition.MyConstant` to a new value. Unlike the class-based solutions with `readonly` fields. However you could use [`as const`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to turn the type of the literal properties into `readonly`:

```js
export default {
    MyConstant: 1234
} as const;
```

`as const` will also narrow the type of those properties as much as possible. So `MyConstant` will be of type `1234` instead of `number`. However with constants this should normally not be a problem.

Comment: If OP didn't have a class and could do away with exporting an object, then `export const MyConstant = 1234;` would be the more sensible choice.

Comment: That's of course an option as well. I didn't list it because OP specifically said they'd like to have them as default export.